# Django admin CSS missing, after collecting static, with python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I run django project on django 1.8.0, with "django manage.py runserver".

It is to be noted that the admin page worked perfectly with CSS a few months ago. However without any change in any file in the project directory (checked with git), the django admin page is missing now its CSS files.

I've noticed that many have had similar problems but I have been unable to solve the problem with their solution. e.g. running manage.py collectstatic.

```
[13/Dec/2015 00:35:00]"GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1931
[13/Dec/2015 00:35:00]"GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1591
[13/Dec/2015 00:35:00]"GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1591
```

[image: the css file is accessed, but missing in the browser.]

As you can see the css file is accessed normally according to the log, but the css file received by the browser is empty.

Your help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

**UDPATE**:
All the files are given the read access as you can see below!
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable DEBUG and enable staticfiles app. If you do not want to enable DEBUG, you may run runserver with --insecure commandline parameter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: Thanks. This helped me out - but why I set debug=True? Would you like to explain me why it doesn't work in production?

Answer (score 0):

[I answer since I cannot comment]
You should check the permissions on these files. Make sure that read access is given to all users !

You can give read access to all with this command
`chmod a+r static_file`